# Returning 0 when count is applied in empty list using LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am working on a list to get count after applying a filter like below

```
ValueRaw = pCounts.Count() > 0 ? pCounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsNew)?.Count : 0
```

above line returns `null` when `pCounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsNew)` is empty

How do I change it to return `0` instead of `null`

Comment: You can use the [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173224.aspx)

Comment: Why do you bother checking `.Count()` at all? If it is 0, then `.SingleOrDefault` will return default anyway? Your whole expression could be this? `pCounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsNew)?.Count ?? 0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this (you don't need your first check):

```
ValueRaw = pCounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsNew)?.Count ?? 0;
```

This uses the null coalising operator (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)). It takes the value left of it if it isn't null and otherwise the value right of it.

However, you could of course still write it with a conditional mark:

```
var temp = pCounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsNew)?.Count;
ValueRaw = temp == null ? 0 : temp;
```

Or even longer with an if:

```
var temp = pCounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsNew)?.Count;
if(temp == null)
    ValueRaw = 0;
else
    ValueRaw = temp;
```

Comment: it can be simplified to pCounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsNew)?.Count ?? 0

Answer (score 3):

First, the `Count()` check is not necessary. `SingleOrDefault` will return default (`null`) when the collection is empty. So your original expression can be simplified to:

```
ValueRaw = pCounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsNew)?.Count;
```

If you want `ValueRaw` to be `0` when no element satisfies the condition, you can use the null-coalescing operator:

```
ValueRaw = pCounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsNew)?.Count ?? 0;
```

This will give you the `Count` of the first element that satisfies the condition, or `0` if there is no such element. In particular, the elements in your collection must themselves be collections (otherwise you cannot apply `Count` to it). Perhaps you actually intend to use `Where`:

```
ValueRaw = pCounts.Where(x => x.IsNew).Count();
```

This will give you the number of elements that satisfy the condition.